# googlebot and layered navigation

Tags: robots.txt

I am having trouble with googlebot crawling through our layered navigation. I get numerous logs like:

```
GET /shop/dresses?clothing_size=250&color=247&dir=desc&limit=15&mode=list&order=position 
GET /shop/dresses?clothing_size=268&color=248&dir=asc&order=name 
GET /shop/sale?clothing_size=252&dir=asc&limit=5&mode=grid&order=name&price=50-100
```

Here is a copy of my robots.txt

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /
Allow: /shop/media/catalog/product/
Allow: /shop/media/wysiwyg/

# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *

# Directories
Disallow: /shop/404/
Disallow: /shop/app/
Disallow: /shop/cgi-bin/
Disallow: /shop/downloader/
Disallow: /shop/errors/
Disallow: /shop/includes/
#Disallow: /shop/js/
#Disallow: /shop/lib/
Disallow: /shop/magento/
#Disallow: /shop/media/
Disallow: /shop/pkginfo/
Disallow: /shop/report/
Disallow: /shop/scripts/
Disallow: /shop/shell/
Disallow: /shop/skin/
Disallow: /shop/stats/
Disallow: /shop/var/
Disallow: /offline/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /shop/index.php/
Disallow: /shop/catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /shop/catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /shop/catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /shop/catalogsearch/
#Disallow: /shop/checkout/
Disallow: /shop/control/
Disallow: /shop/contacts/
Disallow: /shop/customer/
Disallow: /shop/customize/
Disallow: /shop/newsletter/
Disallow: /shop/poll/
Disallow: /shop/review/
Disallow: /shop/sendfriend/
Disallow: /shop/tag/
Disallow: /shop/wishlist/
Disallow: /shop/catalog/product/gallery/

# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt
Disallow: /.DS_Store
Disallow: /api.php
Disallow: /get.php
Disallow: /mage



# Paths (no clean URLs)
#Disallow: /*.js$
#Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?p=*&
Disallow: /*?SID=
```

How can I rewrite my robots.txt to block these urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

robots.txt dont work as expected anymore.
use something simple like in server config:

APACHE:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Googlebot|bingbot|Yahoo) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^clothing_size=([0-9]*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [G]
```

NGINX:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "Baiduspider|Googlebot|bingbot|Yahoo|YandexBot") { set $layered A; }
if ($args ~ ^(clothing_size|color|price)=.+) { set "${layered}B"; }
if ($layered = AB) { return 410; }
```

this will tell bots this page was gone, remove from index also.
you can extend regex to catch more args and bots.

Comment: I'm assuming this goes in .htaccess? Can go anywhere in the file?

Comment: htaccess or httpd config

Comment: I tried implementing your solution in htaccess but afterwards it returned 404 errors for robots.txt and also sitemap.xml???

Comment: there is nothing in these snippets that affects `robots.txt` or `sitemap.xml` you probably has some incorrect changes in htaccess

Comment: @MagenX how about if have another bot craw? because we don't know how many bot index to website

Answer (score 3):

See solution from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/238428/71126) as copy below to fix your issue and prevent bots crawling through your layered navigation

> Denying layered navigation for crawlers and fix SEO issues caused by
>   the huge number of layered navigation URLs can be done by using [PRG
>   Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>
> This works like a charm, i. e. not changing the UX regarding Layered
>   Navigation and 100% reliable in terms of preventing crawlers from
>   wasting crawl budget on useless duplicate content URLs.
>
> Simply said, it's about replacing the GET request to a layered
>   navigation/filter URL with a POST request (which search engine
>   crawlers do not follow) before redirecting the user to the original
>   layered navigation/filter URL.
>
> For further details and reading, please see
>
> 1. [Detailed explanation incl. sample request flow](https://medium.com/@jajuma/the-surprisingly-secret-seo-recipe-prg-pattern-for-advanced-layered-navigation-seo-b32c7cd441fc)
> 2. [Why robots.txt, rel=nofollow etc. are no satisfying solutions here](https://www.jajuma.de/en/blog/seo-optimization-for-layered-navigation-with-prg-pattern)
> 3. [PRG Pattern Magento 2 Extension](https://www.jajuma.de/en/jajuma-develop/extensions/prg-pattern-link-masking-for-magento-2)
> 4. [PRG Pattern Demo](https://demo.extension.jajuma.de/)

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran across this as well and believe I have found a simple solution that works.  Whenever you set up your robots.txt you can simply disallow the attribute attribute.  For example I don't want Google to crawl or index all the potential options for color.

`Disallow: /*color=*`

Just use the attribute code followed by an = and preceded and followed by *.

I spent the last few hours testing in console and it appears to be working smoothly.  I had found a few other potential solutions online but they all ended up having problems that would have caused Google to miss pages that I did want indexed and followed.

Hope this helps someone else out there, it took me way to long to find such a simple solution.